# SQL Select random row based on percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I need a randomizer, but instead of treating all rows equally  (25% each) it needs to treat it based on the percentage assigned to it.

For example:

```
Event Chance_Percentage
A          25.00
B          10.00
C          15.00
D          50.00
```

How would I achieve this?

I am using MySQL.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The syntax for the random number generators will vary.

Comment: @Error_2646 I am using MySql

Comment: @dfundako I did research and tried to figure it out myself but it was treating them as 25% each..

Comment: @confusedOne Show the code.

Comment: It's just a normal select * from mytable order by rand() limit 1. I don't know where to go from this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySQL installed on my machine so this is untested, but I think this general idea will work.

```
    SELECT Event
      FROM Your_Table
     WHERE CASE WHEN Event = 'A' THEN 
                CASE WHEN RAND() <= .25 THEN 1
                     END
                WHEN Event = 'B' THEN 
                CASE WHEN RAND() <= .1 THEN 1
                     END
                WHEN Event = 'C' THEN 
                CASE WHEN RAND() <= .15 THEN 1
                     END
                WHEN Event = 'D' THEN 
                CASE WHEN RAND() <= .5 THEN 1
                     END
            END = 1;
```

Comment: The table I provided was just an example, in my real table I have over 1400 rows and the percentages are calculated based on the sum/overall total, no 2 percentages would be the same. So I don't think manually defining the CASE is the right way to go here since they are 1400 unique percentages:/

Comment: @confusedOne I wouldn't be concerned about performance with 1400 rows. I wouldn't be concerned about the performance of CASE statements in general unless they are in join conditions.

Comment: Ordering of the cases in your example matters. If the % was 9%, both B and C would never get reached because I am pretty sure they would short circuit on the A condition check.

Comment: @confusedOne You'll have to give an example that is representative of your problem. If the percentages change based on other data than that is a different question.

Comment: `rand()` is recalculated each time this is called.  This might return no rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should be rather easy to calculate in an application programming language like Java, Python, C, php, JavaScript or what else you are using. You could just select all your rows into your application and do the calculation there where it is easy to write.

If there is no application NEED to do in on the database then don't do it. Use the right tool for the right job. A database is first of all for persistence and not for calculations.

See also the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You're right, I'm just making this harder for myself.

Comment: @confusedOne . . . Not at all.  This is pretty easy to calculate in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution is:

```
select e.*, t2.*
  from (
    select event,
      (select coalesce(sum(chance_percentage), 0) 
         from table1 t2 where t2.event < t1.event) as lower_bound,
      (select sum(chance_percentage) 
         from table1 t3 where t3.event <= t1.event) as upper_bound
      from table1 t1) e
  join (select 100.0 * rand() as p) t2
    where t2.p >= e.lower_bound and t2.p < e.upper_bound;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select one field with a proba equal to the percent

I think something like this will work fine:
    Set @mybound :=RAND()*100;
    SELECT * FROM Event Where Chance_Percentage < @mybound
    ORDER BY Chance_Percentage desc limit 1

Comment: `rand()` will be recalculated for each row.  It is possible that this will not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do a cumulative sum and then run `rand()` once:

```
select t.event
from (select t.*, (@cume_p = @cume_p + p) as cume_p
      from t cross join
           (select @cume_p := 0, @rand = rand()) params
     ) t
where @rand >= cume_p - p and
      @rand < cume_p;
```

Note that `rand()` is called exactly once.  The value is stored in a variable; that is an arbitrary choice.  It could also be in a subquery:

```
select t.event
from (select t.*, (@cume_p = @cume_p + p) as cume_p
      from t cross join
           (select @cume_p := 0) params
     ) t cross join
     (select rand() as r) r
where r.r >= cume_p - p and
      r.r < cume_p;
```